# Why my git doesn't work with bzr-make?

Tags: bazaar

I want to made deb package for virglrender
in Ubuntu 16.04.

For git i did

```
git clone git://people.freedesktop.org/~airlied/virglrenderer
cd virglrenderer/
ls
./autogen.sh 
make
make install
```

Now I want to package

```
bzr dh-make  virglrenderer 102016git virglrenderer-102016git.tar.gz
```

but it gives me this error

```
bzr: ERROR: Either run the command from an existing branch of upstream, or move virglrenderer/ aside and a new branch will be created there.
```

I did

```
cd ..
```

and redo

```
bzr dh-make  virglrenderer 102016git virglrenderer-102016git.tar.gz
```

but give me this error again

```
bzr: ERROR: Either run the command from an existing branch of upstream, or move virglrenderer/ aside and a new branch will be created there.
```

How to do?
I also tried to create the tar.gz manually with tar,nothing.

Comment: `bzr` stands for "Bazaar". Why are you trying to use a tool designed for bazaar with `git`?

Comment: I though was for packaging from source,sorry i found the command here http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html

Comment: Was there a resolution on this error?